# Retrieve all models from polymorphic many-to-many relation

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I want to retrieve all models involved in polymorphic many-to-many relation. Basing on example given in docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations I want to retrieve `posts()` and `videos()` in one `commentable()` relation.

I know that I can just merge two collections but then I'll have to edit that every time when I'm adding new type of commentable - and I want to avoid that.